# Drivers fail to install on Windows 10 - Saitek Cyborg X

Tags: windows-10, drivers, hardware-detection

I want to install my old Saitek Cyborg X Flight Stick (Not F.L.Y. 5) to my Computer. When i try to install it, the installer (for win 7/8/8.1) won't find my connected stick. (Drivers: http://www.saitek.com/uk/down/drivers.php)

I unpacked the .exe and tried to install the drivers manually; this popup appears:

> **The driver installation file for this device is missing a necessary entry. This may be because the INF was written for Windows 95 or later**

I tried almost everything on the internet or in the FAQ section of saitek, it still doesn't work... (https://logitechsupport.force.com/saitek/s/article/Saitek-device-driver-installer-does-not-complete)

The Profile Editor of my `RAT 7` or `STRIKE TE` doesn't connect to the stick neither...

Some data of my PC:

- CPU: Intel Core i5-4690K @ 3.50 GHz
- GPU: Nvidia Gforce GTX 770 MSI OC
- Mainboard: MSI SLI Krait Edition
- 16 GB Ram
- Windows 10 Pro Version 1511 Build 10586.164

- Stick driver detail: USB\VID_06A3&PID_0836\6&D25860F&1&1
- Stick connected via USB on Mainboard (USB3 & 2)

The whole `INF` file:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Copyright 2007 Saitek plc
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Version]
Signature=    $CHICAGO$
Class=        HIDClass
ClassGuid=    {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}
Provider=     %PROVIDER%
DriverVer=    08/28/2008, 6.5.2.0
CatalogFile=  Sai0836.cat

[Manufacturer]
Saitek =    SAITEK_MODELS, NTamd64

[SAITEK_MODELS.NTamd64]
%HID_NAME%=     SAI_HID_Inst,    HID\VID_06A3&PID_0836
%USB_NAME%=     SAI_USB_Inst,    USB\VID_06A3&PID_0836

[ControlFlags]
ExcludeFromSelect= *

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%DISKNAME%,,,.

[SourceDisksFiles]
SaiK0836.sys = 1 ; programming driver
SaiC0836.Dll = 1 ; control panel
SaiC0836_07.dll = 1   ; german language resources
SaiC0836_09.dll = 1   ; english language resources
SaiC0836_0A.dll = 1   ; spanish language resources
SaiC0836_0C.dll = 1   ; french language resources
SaiC0836_10.dll = 1   ; italian language resources
SaiC0836_11.dll = 1   ; japanese language resources
SaiC0836_0402.dll = 1 ; chinese language resources
WdfCoInstaller01005.dll = 1 ; make sure the number matches with SourceDisksNames

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=     10,system32\drivers
SAI_HID_Inst_CoInstaller_CopyFiles = 11
SAI_HID_Inst_Dlls.CopyFiles.NTamd64 = 11

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[SAI_HID_Inst.NTamd64.CoInstallers]
AddReg=SAI_HID_Inst_CoInstaller_AddReg
CopyFiles=SAI_HID_Inst_CoInstaller_CopyFiles

[SAI_HID_Inst_CoInstaller_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000, "WdfCoInstaller01005.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

[SAI_HID_Inst_CoInstaller_CopyFiles]
WdfCoInstaller01005.dll,,,2

[SAI_HID_Inst.NTamd64.Wdf]
KmdfService = SaiK0836, SAI_HID_Inst_WDFSect

[SAI_HID_Inst_WDFSect]
KmdfLibraryVersion = 1.5

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[SAI_HID_Inst.NTamd64]
Copyfiles = SAI_HID_Inst.CopyFiles.NTamd64, SAI_HID_Inst_Dlls.CopyFiles.NTamd64
AddReg = SAI_HID_Inst.AddReg.NTamd64

[SAI_HID_Inst.CopyFiles.NTamd64]
SaiK0836.sys,,,2

[SAI_HID_Inst_Dlls.CopyFiles.NTamd64]
SaiC0836.Dll
SaiC0836_07.dll
SaiC0836_09.dll
SaiC0836_0A.dll
SaiC0836_0C.dll
SaiC0836_10.dll
SaiC0836_11.dll
SaiC0836_0402.dll

[SAI_HID_Inst.AddReg.NTamd64]
HKLM, %KEY_OEM%\VID_06A3&PID_0836,     OEMName,     0, %DEV_NAME%
HKLM, %KEY_OEM%\VID_06A3&PID_0836,     ConfigCLSID, 0, %GUID_CPL%
HKLM, %KEY_OEM%\VID_06A3&PID_0836,     OEMData, 1,     00, 00, 00, 00, 0E, 00, 00, 00
; cpl
HKCR, CLSID\%GUID_CPL%\ProgID        ,               , ,%USB_NAME%
HKCR, CLSID\%GUID_CPL%\InProcHandler32,              , ,"%11%\gchand.dll"
HKCR, CLSID\%GUID_CPL%\InProcServer32,               , ,"%11%\SaiC0836.dll"
HKCR, CLSID\%GUID_CPL%\InProcServer32, ThreadingModel, ,"Apartment"
; Do I Create a RawPDO for comms
HKR, , UseInterface, 0x00010001, 0
; What Interfaces do I register
HKR, InterfacesSupported, %GUID_TORONTO%,      0x00010001, 1
; Settings for each Interface
; Toronto
HKR, Programming, Alias, ,          %GUID_ALIAS%
HKR, Programming, Balias, ,         %GUID_BALIAS%
;HKR, Programming, CplProfile, ,     %CPL_PROFILE%
;HKR, Programming, DefaultProfile, , %DEFAULT_PROFILE%

[SAI_HID_Inst.NTamd64.Services]
AddService = SaiK0836, 2, SaiHid_Service_Inst

[SaiHid_Service_Inst]
DisplayName    = SaiK0836
ServiceType    = 1
StartType      = 3
ErrorControl   = 1
ServiceBinary  = %12%\SaiK0836.sys

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[SAI_USB_Inst.NTamd64]
Include=Input.inf
Needs=HID_Inst.NTamd64

[SAI_USB_Inst.NTamd64.Services]
Include=Input.inf
Needs=HID_Inst.NTamd64.SERVICES

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[strings]
KEY_OEM       = "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\Joystick\OEM"
CONFIGURATION = "Software\Saitek\Configuration\Controllers"

GUID_SYDNEY       = "{DAF1A7EE-68B2-4757-829E-C3E9226EA2DF}"
GUID_ISTANBUL     = "{A7AAAAD0-99FF-45A1-87F5-2CFAEF10F6A0}"
GUID_CLOCK        = "{EF0BB43B-EF34-4192-8804-D5C0FA4A6A97}"
GUID_CASABLANCA   = "{10DB5451-D30F-4ABC-AB5F-6839C740D0CA}"
GUID_LED          = "{0040FD64-C5F1-49E3-A3EB-38E7B3AB3B3C}"
GUID_MFD          = "{19D936F8-BAC2-4636-82B7-BC2C35F33F2A}"
GUID_DIRECTOUTPUT = "{A131BE63-67FE-4761-A014-EF5AF53742EB}"
GUID_TORONTO      = "{3B0BC249-97F2-49C7-A5B4-8AF34040E48D}"

GUID_CPL          = "{E3D34CBF-E0C3-4B19-84D5-43B8EF4A21D0}"
GUID_ALIAS        = "{48FA7494-A60B-4238-B32F-043129BA03C5}"
GUID_BALIAS       = "{24E74F72-099D-43A2-91BA-8B19E146C678}"

CPL_PROFILE       = "System32\SaiC0836.pr0"
DEFAULT_PROFILE   = "System32\SaiD0836.pr0"

PROVIDER= "Saitek"
DISKNAME= "Saitek Driver Media"
DEV_NAME= "Saitek Cyborg X"
HID_NAME= "Saitek Cyborg X (HID)"
USB_NAME= "Saitek Cyborg X (USB)"
```

Comment: Manually modify the inf, and add support, for Windows 10.  Your not using the current build of 10586, your several months (more than 6) out of date

Comment: @Ramhound how do I modify the inf correctly? The inf in case you need it: http://scshot.deepspace.onl/83c01789-b567-4325-8734-ea44a5d08f6d.inf

Thanks for noticing, I already know that. I have a lot of problems with windows update

Comment: Not going to visit that website in a million years...

Comment: @Ramhound code added

Answer (score -1):

So, this morning I did the Windows 10 x64 1511 build update (November). In doing so, my X52 Pro no longer works, or is acknowledged as being connected via USB. I tired using reinstalling the Saitek beta drivers for Windows 10 x64 to no avail. Currently I am at a loss, as naturally Saitek/MadCatz support is in my opinion the worst in the industry. If anyone else has encountered this issue, and has a workaround, or has gotten their X52 or X52 Pro HOTAS to work on the new Windows 10 x64 build please let me know. Additionalliy, if I myself encounter a solution I will post it here.

To everyone else on Windows 10 x64, be warned that by updating to the new build your HOTAS will no longer function.

My rig's specifications ar ein my Steam profile.

Thanks & goodluck!

-UPDATE 11:39 am EST. I have submitted a ticket to Saitek/MadCatz, as there seems to currently be no way to resolve the issue on the client's end. I will continue to update the information for others who are on the Windows 10 x64 platform as new information, or troubleshooting comes to me. In the meantime, as I previously advised, do not carry out Windows 10 November platform update if you wish to continue using your Saitek product(s).

--UPDATE #2 possible solution: From X-Plane Forums regarding the issue:

--UPDATE #3 SOLUTION ADDED to #2 instructions!

After the major Windows 10 update yesterday (build 1511) my Saitek x52 Pro didn't work anymore. I tried to reinstall, but the installer just hangs and did not detect the X52 being plugged in. After a lot of trial and error I found the following fix:

Plugin the X52

Go to device manager and delete the X52 and USB devices with an ! sign (warning/not installed correctly)

Restart your PC

Unplug your X52

Run the installer (with the latest beta drivers for W10)

When the screen pops up with the instruction to plugin your X52 -> plug it in...

Just let the installer run (with the NEXT button greyed out) and go to device manager

Right click on the X52 device and select update driver

Choose "let me pick" (2nd option) -> you get a list of 2 compatible devices

Now select the 1st option "USB device" or something similar NB: NOT the 2nd one with USB X52 in the name!!!

Directly after this W10 detects your X52 and you can select NEXT in the installer

Install will continue and finish correctly

I wrote the steps down from memory (I don't want to retry with the risk of messing something up) -> BUT the right selection of the USB device (AND NOT X52..) is important. If you select the X52 line you get a critical error and it stops..

This is not my solution but it worked for my Cyborg X for windows 10

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).